# How would I fix this script in order to make the loading screen fade out? - Roblox Studio

Tags: user-interface, lua, roblox, tween

[A picture of the UI I want to fade out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4s0V0.png)

I just started scripting a few weeks ago and have no idea how to fix this problem.

I've looked at a bunch of tutorials and even a very similar problem that another user encountered on this website.

I've tried using tween scripts and the much more inefficient way of just fading it out by changing the background transparency but nothing even affects the UI after pressing the button.

As well as this, I need other GUI elements such as images to fade out with the background.

I am using the following script:

[Code I Am Using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oo1cd.png)

I expected it to tween out after pressing the button but nothing happens. **Please **help me.